# How to call a runbook from another runbook in Orchestrator Runbook Designer

Tags: orchestration, runbook

In System Center 2019 Orchestrator Runbook Designer, I have two runbooks, runbook1 and runbook2. I am trying to call runbook2 from runbook1. When I searched in Google, I found Azure related runbooks automation, But didn't get much information on this Orchestrator Runbooks. May I get any reference for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues initially.
In Google you will get "more correct" results using searches like this

```
SC Orchestrator <activity_name>
```

ie:

```
SC Orchestrator Invoke-Runbook
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/orchestrator/standard-activities/invoke-runbook?view=sc-orch-2019